# How to extract "breed" and "#1097" from variable?

Tags: python, python-re

```
import re
line = "Jan 31 05:23:14 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Commented on ticket [#1097] (breed)"
per_user ={}
pattern = r"ticky: INFO ([\w ]*)"
result = re.search(pattern,line)
name = result[1]
per_user[name] = per_user.get(name,0) +1    
print(per_user)
```

This code is returning this:

> {'Commented on ticket ': 1}

but I want output getting name breed instead of getting 'commented on ticket' and number #1097.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly that you want to grab `breed` as key and the ticket number as value then you need to adjust your regexp and add capture groups for those two elements:

```
import re
line = "Jan 31 05:23:14 ubuntu.local ticky: INFO Commented on ticket 
[#1097] (breed)"
per_user ={}
pattern = r"ticky:\s+INFO.*?\[#(\d+)\]\s+\((.*?)\)$"
result = re.search(pattern,line)
ticket = result.group(1)
name = result.group(2)
per_user[name] = ticket
print per_user
```

Comment: Glad I could help out! Please mark the answer as correct if it served your needs. Thanks!